# If Statement in ELK Stack Filter and Output Part

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have lots of host machines to be logged via ELK stack visualization.(~1000 machine) So I need to do this section apprx. 1000 times as shown below.

```
filter { 
        if [host] =~ /10\.1\.1\.5/ {
            grok {
                add_tag => [ "firewall" ]
                match => [ "message", "<(?<evtid>.*)>(?<datetime>(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\s+(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9]) (?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9])) (?<prog>.*?): (?<msg>.*)" ]
            }
            mutate {
                gsub => ["datetime","  "," "]
            }
            date {
                match => [ "datetime", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
                timezone => "Europe/Istanbul"
            }
            mutate {
                replace => [ "message", "%{msg}" ]
            }
            mutate {
                remove_field => [ "msg", "datetime" ]
            }
        }
    }
```

and this output section again ~1000 times

```
output {
    if [host] =~ /10\.1\.1\.5/ {
        elasticsearch { host => localhost }
    }
}
```

I would like to do in if statement like this How can I do it, AND, OR, etc.?

```
if [host] =~ /10\.1\.1\.5/ && /10\.1\.1\.6/ && /10\.1\.1\.7/ && /10\.1\.1\.8/ ... {}
```

Or any idea other way to do this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/configuration#conditionals) Logstash supports e.g. `and` and `or` in conditional expressions, so you *could* say

```
if [host] =~ /^10\.1\.1\.5$/ or [host] =~ /^10\.1\.1\.6$/ {
  ...
}
```

but that wouldn't be very performant. Instead, try to find a regular expression that matches multiple hosts (maybe all 1000 at once). If you want to include the whole 10.1.1.0/24 subnet for example, do this:

```
if [host] =~ /^10\.1\.1\./ {
  ...
}
```

If that's not possible another option would be to enumerate all IP addresses and use the `in` operator:

```
if [host] in ["10.1.1.5", "10.1.1.6", "10.1.1.7"] {
  ...
}
```

One final option is to somehow tag messages from these hosts so that you don't have to place the condition on the IP address. This seems like the best option, but its feasibility depends on how the logs are collected and shipped.